# trunc / sysdate... funny syntax need explanation

Tags: sql, oracle

I believe this outputs the date of Sunday of the current week but I don't know why. 
Can someone please break down what's going on here.

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate+1,'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What does it do when you try it? What about when you change it to `+ 2` or `+ 4`?

Comment: It returns Sunday's date of this week. I want to know why. I've looked up the syntax of trunc and sysdate and I'm still not getting why. 2 stays at this Sunday 3+ moves to next Sunday

Comment: I think you can find your answer in [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php). This is the syntax of trunk, you can see that when you use `'DAY'` it will return you the Start day of the week.

Comment: It's all documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this to understand what `trunc` does

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(sysdate+1, 'DAY'),'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;
```

`DAY` does returns starting day of the week but `trunc` will also cut off the hours, minutes, seconds of that date. `Sysdate` will have some hours and minutes, but after trunc it is defaulted to 00.00.00.000

By calling this

```
trunc(sysdate+1,'DAY')
```

you may see `16-FEB-14`. You can't see the real result because Oracle doesn't display the minutes for you. If you call this

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate+1,'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;
```

you will see all the time details. Trunk takes that off.

In other words, you have 3 effects here - `sysdate + 1` - next date, `Day` - first day of the week, `Trunc` - hours, minutes, seconds, etc. off

Comment: You can change the NLS Date Format settings of your client to always include the time when showing a date. eg. in Oracle SQL Developer: Tools > Preferences... > Database > NLS
Or you can do alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Comment: This is not the point here. The point is that if you do `Trunc` and then try to get time part of the resulting date, the time will be defaulted to be 00.00.00.000 or 12.00.00.000 AM, whatever you prefer.

Comment: I know, just a side node that "By calling trunc(sysdate+1,'DAY') you can't see the real result" is not always true depending on your NLS.  But indeed by doing the to_char you can always see it.

Comment: @DieterDHoker Agree. I am operating in the mindset of the person who asks this kind of question. I try to envision what they see and why they ask :o))

Answer (score 2):

The TRUNC function will return the starting day of the week when the second parameter is DAY. Today Sysdate returns Thursday, +1 returns Friday etc. So when you add  3 it gives you next Sunday which marks the start of a new week.

Answer (score 0):

see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm

'DAY' truncates the date provided to the starting day of the week. 
Note that depending on your locale this can also be Monday instead of Sunday.

sysdate + 1 just adds one day to the current date, this is probably done to make sure if you are sunday you get back the current sunday and not the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

select to_char(sysdate+1,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;----22-feb-14 02:10:03

select to_char(trunc(sysdate+1,'year'),'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;-----01-jan-14 00:00:00

select  to_char(trunc(sysdate+1,'month'),'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') from dual; ---01-feb-14 00:00:00

select  to_char(trunc(sysdate+1,'day'),'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') from dual; ---16-feb-14 00:00:00

*Compare above queries outputs, hope this will help you.*